# What term means "words that look alike and mean alike, across two languages"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term, perhaps used by linguists, that refers to two words that have a similar form, either written or spoken, and almost identical meaning or at least relatively similar, but appearing in two languages?

I found some terms similar to this meaning, such as "cognate", which requires that the words have a shared origin, and "false cognate", which requires that the words have no shared origin. Is there a single term that includes both cognates and false cognates, as I have no concern for whether the words share an origin or not?

Comment: See also [linguistics.se]

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. But I do know what the French call words which mean one thing in French and something else in English - *faux amis* (false friends). There are hundreds of them. Some which have totally different meanings and others where the meaning is slightly different in French. I well remember the occasion in my youth when I refused more food from a French hostess, to guffaws of laughter around the table, when I said - *Je suis plein* (lit. I am full), which is a crude way of saying 'I'm pregnant'!

Comment: For instance, what is the term that describes the fact that *doctor* is the same spelling and definition in Spanish and English? Borrowed words? Word appropriation?

Comment: Cognates are words/morphemes that derive from the parent language of two languages. Borrowings are borrowed after the two languages are already distinct. If they're neither cognates nor borrowings, then they're probably false cognates/friends with bigger semantic differences than you realise. If there really is no semantic difference then you'd call it a coincidence! But there are very few of those, perhaps just *mama* and *papa*.

Comment: @Village: Because true synonyms are very rare (some linguists would even say they don't exist) the origin of words is important. Cognates are likely to have some shared meaning. Borrowings could be even more similar, or potentially less similar, both happen when words are borrowed. If there really is no genetic history connecting the languages then the words probably aren't actually synonymous at all!

Comment: @SrJoven: but English _doctor_ and Spanish _doctor_ seem cognates with a shared etymological origin in Latin.

Comment: Oerk - no, you're wildly over thinking it. the OP is very simply asking "whaddya call it when the word is the same in french and english".  That's all.

Comment: @curiousdannii There are at least a few other famous coincidental ones: Farsi _bad_ means ‘bad’ but is etymologically unrelated; German _haben_ and Latin _habere_ both mean ‘have’ and both have the stem _hab(e)-_ but are etymologically unrelated; Greek _θεός_ (_theós_) [stem _θεό-_], Latin _deus_ [stem _deo-_], and Nāhutal _teotl_ [stem _teo-_] all mean approximately ‘God’ but are unrelated; etc.

Comment: @oerkelens No, _cognate_ would not answer the question “What do you call the phenomenon of _X_ being represented in two different languages by words that are (nearly) identical?”. Loan words and common neologisms would be examples of such a case, but they are not cognates.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet well all those examples are from Indo-European languages. I don't know the details of their etymologies, but ruling out cognates and borrowings would be rather hard to do.

Comment: @curiousdannii Nāhuatl is not Indo-European; it's Uto-Aztecan. All the words I mentioned have very firmly established etymologies and are classic examples of coincidental similarity.

Comment: I'm sure I've heard the term 'friendly word' used by a language teacher, but as I cannot find evidence for it, I won't call it an answer. It seems the obvious counterpart to the 'false friend' term mentioned by @WS2

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Someone told me that the *bad* in *Islamabad* meant *bath*, as it does in German; the city being a spa. Was there any truth in this or were they having me on?

Comment: @WS2 Having you on, I'm afraid. [_-abad_](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/-abad) is really just the Persian (and Urdu) word _ābād_, meaning ‘city’, so _Islām ābād_ means ‘city of Islam’.

Answer (score 6):

There are several reasons why words in two languages might sound and mean similarly.

1. One (or both) of the words may be borrowed,
   like *radio, curry,* or *tea,* in many unrelated languages.
2. One of the words may be a descendant from the same source as the other,
   like Spanish articles *el, la* and Italian articles *il, la*.
   (Words related like this are called ***Cognates*** < [Lat *co-g(e)natus* 'born together](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gen.pdf)')
3. It may simply be an accident,
   like English *hole* and Yucatec Maya /ho:l/ 'hole', or Latin *dua* '2' and Malay *duwa* '2'.
   It is estimated that any two languages have around half-a-dozen such pairs, on the average,
   and they provide no evidence for anything except the vagaries of lexical sound and meaning.

In any event, there is no term that covers all and only these phenomena.

Comment: And there's a fourth group, too, that of universal applicability (for lack of a better term, though it's not universal): _mama/papa_ words, various onomatopoeia, etc.

Comment: Onomatopoeia is surprisingly diverse. And there's very little interlanguage universalism in sound symbolism.

Comment: Despite their diversity, onomatopoeia for a loud explosion tend to have an initial bilabial plosive and (if possible) a final nasal in a lot more languages than chance would allow. Same goes for creaking and initial velars/uvulars, and for flowing water and sibilants.

Answer (score 2):

I feel what you're asking has nothing to do with "cognates".  "Cognates" is a highly technical term relating of the origin of words.

I believe you're simply asking "what the hell do you call it when the word is the same in two languages?"

Surprisingly I think there **is no word for such a thing** and that's the answer.

{Going back to cognates. Say there was a word, X, for what you ask.  Linguists and specialists would then say "oh, most X are due to them being cognates." But sometimes X is simply due to loan words ("tv") or other reasons, or coincidence.  You're simply asking for the term for "same word in both languages" -- again surprisingly IMO there is no such word.}

Note that today the socially correct answer for SWR, where, the answer is "there's no such word", is "there's no such word."

I'm pretty sure that's the answer in this case (surprisingly!)

Comment: Cognates are one explanation for "X".

Comment: @oerkelens Loan words do not usually fall under the category of cognates. Cognates are words that evolve _separately_ in related languages, from a common ancestral source. Loan words have evolve _once_ in one language and are then borrowed piecemeal into another. For example, _name_ in English and _nom_ in French are cognates; but _nom de plume_ in French and English are not cognates—that’s just a loan word. _Noun_ is arguably cognate with French _nom_, since it has developed separately within English since it was borrowed from Norman French.

Comment: "Noun" and "nom" are generally not considered to be cognates, at least in historical linguistics, simply because however "noun" has developed, it was still originally a borrowed word. A cognate has to date back to the time when the languages originally split.

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be applying *congruent*/*congruency*/*[congruous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/congruous)* to the term. [Congruent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/congruent), according to the FreeDictionary, means coinciding exactly when superimposed and generally relates to math(s)/geometry.

If one were to apply the term to "the same word, that looks alike and mean alike", I wouldn't find it incongruous to apply a term that feels like *matching* to words.

Answer (score 1):

Just call it a shared word.  English and French for instance have many shared words.  Some of them are borrowed, some are cognates, some are false cognates and some are simply onamonapias.  But the point you are looking for is simply that they exist in both locations.

Comment: A very sensible solution!  Merry Xmas !